# Django CMS - Transfer content between languages

Tags: python, django, django-cms, django-multilingual

I have set up an Djando CMS site, using english language, I would like to transfer all the input for english to spanish.

I have both english and spanish installed on my application, but the spanish is now mostly empty, while the english is filled up with content.

How can I populate the spanish language module, with the input already filled out in the english module?

Answer (score 1):

Django CMS has a [copy_lang](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/support-3.0.x/reference/cli.html#cms-copy-lang) command to copy from a language to another

```
./manage.py cms copy_lang en sp
```

Double check the language codes please